# SELECT INTO TARGET_TABLE on specific FILEGROUP

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to clone a table's data structure to another table programmatically. As a start I tried to copy the schema of the table using the following query

```
SELECT * INTO TARGET_TABLE FROM SOURCE_TABLE WHERE 1<>1
```

But for my situation I specifically need the newly created table to be in a specific FILEGROUP only. something like the below

```
SELECT * INTO TARGET_TABLE ON [NEW_FILEGROUP] FROM SOURCE_TABLE WHERE 1<>1
```

I know the above line will work starting with `SQL Server 2017` version. However whatsoever app I'm trying to make, should support from `SQL Server 2016`. What is the closest/easiest thing I can make use of in this case?

Comment: Your query does not return any records due to condition 1 <> 1

Comment: @گلی exactly. I just need to copy the data structure

Comment: Upgrade to 2016 SP2, then you can do `SELECT` with `FILEGROUP` no problem. Considering earlier versions are out of support, you should do that anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The real struggle was to get it done programmatically.**

Till sql-server 2016 SP1, mentioning a filegroup in `select into` statement is not possible. As a work around solution, what I did to sort this out is that I've added an `Unique clustered index` to the newly created table. The advantage is that I can mention the filegroup while creating an index

```
SELECT * INTO TARGET_TABLE FROM SOURCE_TABLE WHERE 1<>1
    
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [target_table_clustered_idx] ON TARGET_TABLE
(
    unique_column ASC
) ON [NEW_FILEGROUP]
```

Since this is a clustered index, the db engine will move the entire table and the index to the `[NEW_FILEGROUP]`. Hence solved

Answer (score -2):

@Beingnin  . Right click on the table then click on "Script Table as " then Click on " CREATE To " then "New Query Editor Window" Like Below Picture. then you can get
Complete  script of table.
[image]

Comment: I appreciate the effort. But like I said it need to be done programmatically and also it is important that it need to be in a separate file group

Comment: please send me more info about "separate file group" @Beingnin

Comment: a file group other than `[PRIMARY]`